# Cocoa error 3840 using JSON (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to send data to a server and receive the response in JSON format. The problem is that the server has to return "success" or "fail" but it returns "(null)".

Here's the returned error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=XXXXXXXXX
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

Is it possible that the error is in the server script?

Here's my function to send the data and receive the response:

```
- (void) putData:(NSString *)parameter valor:(NSString *)valor {

    NSString *rawString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", parameter, valor];
    NSData *data = [rawString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@ error: %@", json, error);
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unless you pass the option `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` to `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]` the response from the server must be valid JSON with a top level container which is an array or dictionary.

for example:

```
    { "response" : "Success" }
```

P.S.
If you want a mutable dictionary you must also include `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` in your options.

Comment: What you're saying is that the mistake might be in the PHP code?

Comment: I is likely JSONP, so JSON, but wrapped in a method named something like callback(_all your JSON here);

Comment: @RickiG So, If you have no control over the server's response, how would you get by this? By using NSJSONReadingAllowFragments ? If that's the case, does this automatically parse the containing JSON? How would you hanlde it as a response? Thanks!

Comment: @Stu i cant solve this issue with or without NSJSONReadingAllowFragments

Comment: Also you should try AFHTTPResponseSerializer (instead AFJSONResponseSerializer). It works for me

Answer (score 10):

It may possible that, the response from your server doesn't contain valid JSON.

Technically, The JSON object must be start with either an "array" or an "object (dictionary)".

So, Whatever your server is returning isn't.

And, you can force the JSON to be consumed regardless by using the NSJSONReadingAllowFragments option.

by using ,

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

Comment: Also you should try AFHTTPResponseSerializer (instead AFJSONResponseSerializer). It works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can get this issue if you're connected to VPN on your iOS device.