# How to resolve error:the operation couldn’t be completed. (cocoa error 3840.) json iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, redmine

I wrote the GET method code to retrieve the details from server(json format).But I am getting the error (the operation could not be completed).
can anyone please provide me some information regarding this?
My code:

```
-(void)getResponseWithOutBodywithMethod:(NSString*)method
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:method];

//[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// [request setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
 NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn)
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init] ;
}
}
#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:  (NSURLResponse *)response{
/* This method is called when the server has determined that it has
 enough information to create the NSURLResponse. It can be called
 multiple times, for example in the case of a redirect, so each time
 we reset the data. */
[receivedData setLength:0];
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:  (    NSData *)data{
[receivedData appendData:data];
 }
 - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(  NSError *)error{
completion(nil, error);
NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

  }
    - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

if (receivedData != nil) {
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&jsonParsingError];

    NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"error %@",jsonParsingError.localizedDescription);
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ER" message:str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
    if (dict == nil && [dict count]==0) {

             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:jsonParsingError.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
         completion(nil, jsonParsingError);
    }
    else {

        completion(dict, nil);



    }
}
else {
    completion(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:@"http" code:-1 userInfo:nil]); //todo proper error
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to get data." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Comment: pls  go through this link it may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171111/cocoa-error-3840-using-json-ios

Comment: I tried the above link,but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Well I would think your Json is the problem.

If your server is responding:

Something=somethingelse

That's not the proper format. You would need to Json encode it so it looks like:

[{"key":"value", "key":"value"}]

Comment: I didn't send the data just I am retrieving the details using url

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YourURL.com/FakeURL/PARAMETERS"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; NSURLResponse *requestResponse;

NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];