# json parsing failed - cocoa error 3840 and invalid value around character 0

Tags: php, ios, json, parsing, ios8

I know a lot of questions have addressed this issue but I have not found one that helped me...

When I parse json data downloaded from a localhost (MAMP server), I face the json error 3840 stating invalid value around character 0...

I don't understand why, since my php script with a var_dump on my array displays (an array of array):

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["EDS"]=> string(4) "1000" ["lastname"]=> string(8) "My lastname" ["firstname"]=> string(9) "My firstname" ["dateOfBirth"]=> string(10) "19.12.1975" } [1]=> array(5) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["EDS"]=> string(4) "1001" ["lastname"]=> string(14) "Smith" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "John" ["dateOfBirth"]=> string(10) "11.11.1111" } }
```

...which for me seems to be a valid json array.

When I log the NSMutableData downloaded, it is not null, but something like

```
76353648 2734b0a9 (+ around fifty like this).
```

I don't know if it is because the data is not complete, but I don't know how I can keep on analyzing a little further what is going wrong.

If anyone has an idea of what happens (I understand it has to do with a special character not recognized), it would be great.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Added followup code to the original question:

In

```
(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    NSArray *deserializedArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;

    for (NSDictionary *jsonElement in deserializedArray)
        {
        Person *newPersonElement = [[PersonStore sharedStore] createPerson]; // --> what makes the app crash. But this method is working everywhere else...
    // more code omitted
}
```

I don't know why this initialization crashes here...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14171349/1960712) answer would help you.

Comment: what does the api return when you call it from browser ? And add your php code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

I think now that you have posted the Objective-C code that uses this received JSON, it becomes clear what the actual problem is.

It sounds to me that you are using Core Data (`PersonStore`) to persist your incoming data.

If you are making Core Data calls from the same thread that `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is being called on, you are most likely running into a threading issue where Core Data is not happy that you call it from a thread other than the main thread.

Give this a try: in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` wrap your code in the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Include the code here that walks over the incoming JSON
    // and creates new `Person` instances.
});
```

This will execute everything in that block, on the main thread. Which is generally a good idea for Core Data usage. (Probably even required, check the documentation, there is a special section on Core Data & Threads if I remember correctly).

Very curious if this does the trick.

**Old answer:**

The output of `vardump` is not actually valid JSON. You need to use the `json_encode()` function instead.

You can turn the `NSData` that you received from the server into a string by doing something like this:

```
if let s = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    println(s)
}
```

You did not mention if you work in Swift or Objective-C but the above translates easily to Objective-C.

Comment: I use obj-C. The fact is that I use json_encode() but I test with var_dump just to see how it looks like. What is strange is that when I remove the var_dump my mutableData is null. Is it possible since I json_encode() the same array that the one I passed in with var_dump (which looks like a json structure)? I am a bit lost (even though I will try your string conversion advice)...

Comment: The output of var_dump() goes into the page output. So it would be part of the JSON that you are trying to decode. Can you share your PHP code?

Comment: I put my php script above... It looks like an error must be in my obj-c code since something new happens: my app crashes without the var_dump() (i.e only with the json_encode()

Comment: Thanks so much! Apparently that did the trick! You are a genius! :-). Thanks for your help, really appreciated!!