# Cocoa error 3840

Tags: ios, xcode6, afnetworking

I'm trying send post request to server with `AFNetworking 2.0`

```
NSDictionary * dict = @{@"credentials": @{
                                @"name": @"Valod",
                                @"password": @"test"
                                }
                        };

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[manager POST:URL parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];`
```

but I'm getting the error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fd6214a5d70 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd62150ec60 "Request failed: internal server error (500)"}

I test api call with google application.And the response **json is valid json**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa error 3840 using JSON (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171111/cocoa-error-3840-using-json-ios)

Comment: I see this post but it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your requestSerializer, maybe it 's AFHTTPRequestSerializer instead of AFJSONRequestSerializer.
Try setting `manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];`