# get responseObject on failure block AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

how can I get the response string from failure block in AFNetworking 3.x,

In the 2.x version the way to do it was:

```
[manager GET:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary_FetchResult = responseObject;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary_FetchResult = operation.responseObject;
}];
```

but in the 3.x version there is no operation in the returning block's parameter as shown below:

```
[manager POST:path parameters:parameters progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary_FetchResult = responseObject;
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

so I was hoping if someone was able to achieve that.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just do this in your failure block:-

```
 NSString* errResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",errResponse);
```

**For Swift:-**

```
var errResponse: String = String(data: (error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as! NSData), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
NSLog("%@", errResponse)
```

**Updated for Swift 4.1**

```
var errResponse: String = String(data: (error._userInfo![AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as! Data), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
print(errResponse)
```

Comment: what to do in swift?

Comment: what if i want to download image from url ios

Comment: @Vizllx will the AppStore reject if I use error._userInfo

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution for this which works perfectly. In swift

```
if let userInfo : NSDictionary = error.userInfo as NSDictionary {
     if let innerError : NSError = userInfo.objectForKey("NSUnderlyingError") as? NSError {

         if let innerUserInfo : NSDictionary = innerError.userInfo as NSDictionary {

              if innerUserInfo.objectForKey(AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey) != nil {
                   let StrError = NSString(data: innerUserInfo.objectForKey(AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey) as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                   print(StrError)
              }
         } else if let errResponse: String = String(data: (error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as! NSData), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
              print(errResponse)
         }
     }

}
```

and Objective-C code is

```
    NSDictionary *userinfo1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:error.userInfo];

if(userinfo1) {
      NSError *innerError = [userinfo1 valueForKey:@"NSUnderlyingError"];
      if(innerError) {
         NSDictionary *innerUserInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:innerError.userInfo];
         if(innerUserInfo)
         {
              if([innerUserInfo objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey])
              {
                   NSString *strError = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[innerUserInfo objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            NSLog(@"Error is : %@",strError);
              }
         }
      } else
      {
           NSString *errResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[userinfo1 valueForKey:@"AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

          if(errResponse)
          {
               NSLog(@"%@",errResponse);
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)requestWithURL:(NSString *)url parameterDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)data  requestType:(NSString *)reqType  handler:(NSObject *)handler selector:(SEL)selector
{

  // reqType is POST or GET
  // handler would be self if you define selector method in same class
  AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

  NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:reqType URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] parameters:nil error:nil];

req.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
if (data != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Data is not nil");
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}else{
    NSLog(@"Data is nil");
}

[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {
//            NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [handler performSelector:selector withObject:responseObject];
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            //blah blah
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
        [handler performSelector:selector withObject:responseObject];
    }
}] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution at [GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2410):

```
@interface ResponseSerializer : AFJSONResponseSerializer
@end

@implementation ResponseSerializer

- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                       data:(NSData *)data
                      error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)errorPointer
{
    id responseObject = [super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:errorPointer];
    if (*errorPointer) {
        NSError *error = *errorPointer;
        NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [error.userInfo mutableCopy];
        userInfo[@"responseObject"] = responseObject;
        *errorPointer = [NSError errorWithDomain:error.domain code:error.code userInfo:[userInfo copy]];
    }
    return responseObject;
}

@end
```

And then assign it to your manager:

```
self.manager.responseSerializer = [ResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let responseData:NSData = (error as NSError).userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as! NSData
let s :String = String(data: responseData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

For Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Fixed some code here, properly handling optionals. Swift 3(.1)...

```
let nserror = error as NSError
if let errordata = nserror.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as? Data {
    if let errorResponse = String(data: errordata, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print("errorResponse: \(errorResponse)")
    }
}
```