# Swift Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 " Problems with my Login Controller "

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift, parsing

This is my code and I am unable to compile it .
I am trying to login to my server but it doesnt allow me so
Sorry I am new at programming and I've researched on stackoverflow, regarding this error , I can only parse Dictionary or Array. but I've googled by copying my JSON response but it doesnt work.
Any Suggestions would be helpful !!

```
import UIKit

class Login: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Password: UITextField!



@IBAction func Login(sender: UIButton) {


    let username=Username.text
    let password=Password.text

    let URL_LOGIN="http://172.22.95.116/SoilCondition/app/getLogin.php?USERNAME=" + username! + "&PASSWORD=" + password!;

    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_LOGIN)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"



    let postParameters = "username="+username!+"&password="+password!;

    request.HTTPBody =            postParameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in guard let data = data where error == nil
            else {
                print("error: \(error)")
                return
        }

        do{
            let myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,  options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = myJSON{

                var msg: String!
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                print(msg)
            }

           /* if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                var msg : String!

                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                print(msg)
            }*/
            /*if data != nil {
                json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
                println("json: \(json)")

                if let dictionary = parseJSON(jsonString) {
                    println("dictionary: \(dictionary)")
                }*/
        } catch let parseError{
            print(parseError)
            }
        }
    task.resume()
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171111/cocoa-error-3840-using-json-ios) regarding error code 3840.

As it says there, the problem could be that your server doesn't return valid JSON to you.

Now, you say:

> I can only parse Dictionary or Array

I don't know if that means that you are able to actually parse the response you receive from the server into valid JSON here:

```
let myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,  options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

But if it doesn't then a good place to start could be to verify whether your server actually returns valid JSON to you.

To do so, you could try calling your server directly from [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se) or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com) and see what you get in return.

Hope that helps you.